# Add columns where identifiers fit multiple patterns

Tags: r, loops, apply, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

A data frame `df` has one row per for every distinct value of its numeric vector `id0` - but trailing zeros in cells for `id0` indicate important groups along which the file must be transformed. Here are 12 observations of `df`:

```
row id0     id0_ntz
a   111000  3
b   111010  1
c   112345  0
d   111974  0
e   112090  1
f   114000  3
g   114099  0
h   555001  0
i   555012  0
j   461000  3
k   461020  1
l   111090  0
```

Let's call every value of `id0` with three trailing zeros (i.e., where `id0_ntz == 3`) a "**big id**" and every value that doesn't fit this pattern a "**little id**." The 12 obs above include three **big ids** (`row` values `a`, `f`, and `j`). For each **big id**, I need to:

1. Find every other value of `id0` that matches the *first three digits* of this *i*th **big id**
2. Add the value of `id0` for each match to one of *j* discrete vectors called `idj`, where *j* is a suffix ranging from 1 to *j* that effectively counts the number of matching **little ids** nested in the *i*th **big id**.

If `df` only included the 12 rows shown above, the correct result would look like this:

```
row id0     id0_ntz id1     id2     id3
a   111000  3       111010  111974  111090
b   111010  1       NA      NA      NA
c   112345  0       NA      NA      NA
d   111974  0       NA      NA      NA
e   112090  1       NA      NA      NA
f   114000  3       114099  NA      NA
g   114099  0       NA      NA      NA
h   555001  0       NA      NA      NA
i   555012  0       NA      NA      NA
j   461000  3       461020  NA      NA
k   461020  1       NA      NA      NA
l   111090  0       NA      NA      NA
```

I'm open to any solution that solves this problem dynamically (i.e., is agnostic to the number of **big ids**, **little ids**, and resulting `idj` vectors).

P.S.: I need to do the same thing again where `id0_ntz == 2`, then `1`, but an acceptable answer to this posted question only requires a solution that solves the problem where `id0_ntz == 3`.

Comment: seems like `df[1,6]` is an error/typo?  there is no `111090` in `id0` ?

Comment: this is not a typo - `111090` appears in `df[12,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the approach below. Its quite short.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(big_id = substr(id0, 1, 3)) %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(substr(id0, 4, 6) == "000",
                     list(setdiff(unique(id0),
                                  paste0(big_id, "000"))),
                     list())) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col = id,
               names_sep = "")

#> # A tibble: 12 x 7
#> # Groups:   big_id [5]
#>    row      id0 id0_ntz big_id    id1    id2    id3
#>    <chr>  <int>   <int> <chr>   <int>  <int>  <int>
#>  1 a     111000       3 111    111010 111974 111090
#>  2 b     111010       1 111        NA     NA     NA
#>  3 c     112345       0 112        NA     NA     NA
#>  4 d     111974       0 111        NA     NA     NA
#>  5 e     112090       1 112        NA     NA     NA
#>  6 f     114000       3 114    114099     NA     NA
#>  7 g     114099       0 114        NA     NA     NA
#>  8 h     555001       0 555        NA     NA     NA
#>  9 i     555012       0 555        NA     NA     NA
#> 10 j     461000       3 461    461020     NA     NA
#> 11 k     461020       1 461        NA     NA     NA
#> 12 l     111090       0 111        NA     NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This will serve your purpose

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'row id0     id0_ntz
a   111000  3
b   111010  1
c   112345  0
d   111974  0
e   112090  1
f   114000  3
g   114099  0
h   555001  0
i   555012  0
j   461000  3
k   461020  1
l   111090  0', header = T)
df$id0 <- as.character(df$id0)
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(id0_ntz == 3) %>%
  mutate(big_id = substr(id0, 1, 3)) -> big_id

df %>% mutate(id0 = as.character(id0)) %>%
  left_join(df %>% mutate(id = as.character(id0),
                          dummy = match(substr(id, 1, 3), big_id$big_id)) %>%
              filter(!is.na(dummy)) %>%
              group_by(dummy) %>%
              mutate(d2 = paste0('id', row_number() - 1)) %>% select(-id0) %>%
              pivot_wider(id_cols = dummy, names_from = d2, values_from = id),
            by = c('id0')) %>%
  select(-dummy)
#>    row    id0 id0_ntz    id1    id2    id3
#> 1    a 111000       3 111010 111974 111090
#> 2    b 111010       1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 3    c 112345       0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 4    d 111974       0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 5    e 112090       1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 6    f 114000       3 114099   <NA>   <NA>
#> 7    g 114099       0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 8    h 555001       0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 9    i 555012       0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 10   j 461000       3 461020   <NA>   <NA>
#> 11   k 461020       1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#> 12   l 111090       0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = 'row id0     id0_ntz
a   111000  3
b   111010  1
c   112345  0
d   111974  0
e   112090  1
f   114000  3
g   114099  0
h   555001  0
i   555012  0
j   461000  3
k   461020  1
l   111090  0', header = T)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = id0 %/% 1000 * 1000) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number() - 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(row_id != 0) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = row_id, values_from = id0, names_prefix = "id") %>% 
  right_join(df, by = c("id" = "id0")) %>% 
  rename(id0 = id) %>% 
  arrange(row)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 6
#>       id0    id1    id2    id3 row   id0_ntz
#>     <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int> <chr>   <int>
#>  1 111000 111010 111974 111090 a           3
#>  2 111010     NA     NA     NA b           1
#>  3 112345     NA     NA     NA c           0
#>  4 111974     NA     NA     NA d           0
#>  5 112090     NA     NA     NA e           1
#>  6 114000 114099     NA     NA f           3
#>  7 114099     NA     NA     NA g           0
#>  8 555001     NA     NA     NA h           0
#>  9 555012     NA     NA     NA i           0
#> 10 461000 461020     NA     NA j           3
#> 11 461020     NA     NA     NA k           1
#> 12 111090     NA     NA     NA l           0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>